# Jquery File Tree - with root folder icon that will collapse the filebrowser

Tags: jquery, file, file-browser, filetree

I am using jquery file tree (http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/). and i want to add an icon for the root folder that when click, it will collapse the open folders and files, just display the immediate directory below the root folder (somewhat of refresh,restart).

I was able to show collapse the directory but when i click on the child directory it will not expand now.

Anyone experienced the same problem before.